# How to stop the Facebook app from updating itself automatically?

Tags: facebook

I have the Facebook app installed on my Android 7 phone.

- Auto-update is disabled for all applications on my Play Store account
- I have disabled installation from unknown sources

For some reason, whenever there is an update of the Facebook app, it automatically updates itself even though I disabled auto-updates for all applications.

How to stop the Facebook app from updating itself automatically?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update**: The settings location was changed, now at:

**Settings & Privacy --> Settings --> Media and Contacts --> App Updates --> Auto-Update Facebook**

---

Open your Facebook mobile app and navigate to that location to turn off the option:

(From the three lines icon at the top, at the bottom you'll have *Settings & Privacy* which should be expanded).

S̶e̶t̶t̶i̶n̶g̶s̶ ̶&̶ ̶P̶r̶i̶v̶a̶c̶y̶ ̶-̶-̶>̶ ̶A̶p̶p̶ ̶S̶e̶t̶t̶i̶n̶g̶s̶ ̶-̶-̶>̶ ̶A̶p̶p̶ ̶U̶p̶d̶a̶t̶e̶s̶ ̶-̶-̶>̶ ̶A̶u̶t̶o̶-̶U̶p̶d̶a̶t̶e̶ ̶F̶a̶c̶e̶b̶o̶o̶k̶

Comment: Wow thank you. I didn't know facebook had its own auto update "feature" bypassing the android OS or playstore one.

Comment: There is no such option as 'App Updates' and the Gif you have moves too fast.

Comment: I've updated my answer, the setting has been moved.

Comment: Looks like the setting is removed... again...

Comment: where is it now. Couldn't find it :(