# Prevent Facebook app from getting automatically updated on Samsung device

Tags: google-play-store, samsung, facebook, application-autoupdate

I have my auto-update turned off for all my apps on the Play Store. Still, I have noticed that my Facebook app shows updated 3 days ago. This happened today. I have noticed the same problem before 5th October 2021. This is happening only with my Facebook app and no other apps.

I have also checked my Galaxy Store to see if Facebook is being updated from that store. But there is no Facebook app in the Galaxy store (Samsung) whereas there are other apps like Facebook Lite, etc. there.

Can someone please tell me why is my Facebook app getting updated automatically and what should I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Does your device comes with a second app store such as Galaxy Store (Samsung)? If there is a second store the app update can be installed by this store. See also https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/234390/why-do-play-store-apps-show-in-galaxy-store

Comment: Yes I have Galaxy store but in galaxy store, there is no app named Facebook. It has Facebook lite and other apps but in my play store, it appeared that the Facebook app has got updated automatically. Then can you please tell what should I do?

Comment: If the Facebook app was preinstalled on your device it may be automatically updated via Play Store. For other preinstalled Google apps this is a known feature of Play Store. If it also updates preinstalled third party apps I don't know, it is just a guess that this might be possible, too. Related question on Play Store auto update: [How do I stop the Google app from automatically updating?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/239037/2241)

Comment: Possibly related/duplicate: [How to stop the Facebook app from updating itself automatically?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/195037/44325). Might also want to check this: [Facebook Help Center - How do I enable or disable Facebook app updates on my phone?](https://www.facebook.com/help/android-app/812681095504818)